# Too much space between a float and the section that follows it

Tags: floats, sectioning, vertical-spacing

When a section follows a float, the vertical space between the two elements is too large, as `\intextsep` is added to the spacing introduced by `\section`. Generally speaking, this is also true for other commands (such as `\mycommand` in the MWE below) that add vertical spacing. Consider the MWE and the following images as an example :

[image]

And :

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mwe, lipsum}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mycommand}{\par%
    \vspace{16pt    \@plus 4pt  \@minus 2pt}%
    {\centering\LARGE * * *\par}%
    \vspace{16pt    \@plus 4pt  \@minus 2pt}%
    \@afterindentfalse\@afterheading}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering\includegraphics[width =.5\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{Figure \#1.}
\end{figure}

\mycommand\lipsum[2]
\mycommand\lipsum[2]
\newpage\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering\includegraphics[width =.5\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{Figure \#2.}
\end{figure}

\section{My section}\lipsum[2]
\section{My section}\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Of course, I don't want `\intextsep` to equal 0 when the float is followed by text. So I can't simply write `\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}`.

So I tried using `\removelastskip` or `\addvspace{...}` instead of `\vspace{...}` to compensate for the space added by `\intextsep` but to no avail...

Do you know how to make the vertical space of an `\intextsep` value placed at the top and bottom of a float behave like `\addvspace` so that the macro located after the float can use `\addvspace`, `\removelastskip` etc?

---

Interestingly, a similar problem is referenced in the LaTeX2e source document (page 1081 of the 2023-11-01 version):

> 8. Two consecutive h floats are separated by twice \intextsep: this could be changed to one by use of \addvspace, OK? Note that it would
>    also mean that less space is put in if an h float immediately follows
>    other spaces. This is also possibly too big a change, at least for
>    compatibility mode? Or it may be simply wrong! It has not been
>    changed.

As suggested, I'd like to use floats using `\addvspace` (or at least similar behaviour). It's mentioned that this would be a *big change*, I don't know if that's to refer to the complexity of modifying the original code or to refer to the changes that would be found in the output documents and the resulting lack of backwards compatibility. Nevertheless, the commands for managing floats are far too complex for me and go far beyond my understanding of LaTeX. Naive use of `\patchcmd{\@addtocurcol}{\skip\intextsep}{\addvspace{\intextsep}}{}` did not, of course, solve the problem.

Comment: How about `\vskip-\intextskip` when needed?  Also, make sure `\belowcaptionskip` is 0pt (use `\the\belowcaptionskip` to print the value, or add `\hrule` below the caption inside the figure).

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thank you, but I'm actually looking for an automatic solution rather than a manual one. It seems to me that `\belowcaptionskip` is equal to 0 pt for standard documentclasses (article and book).

Comment: I don't think an automatic solution is possible.  figure has no way of knowing that it will wind up in front of a \section and \section has no way on knowing there is a figure iin front of it (remember, floats can move around).  Besides, "too much space" is an aesthetic judgement (depends on the person).

Comment: @JohnKormylo That's right, but if the vertical space `\intextskip` introduced before and after the float behaved like `\addvspace`, there's no need for the section to know that it's just after a float or vice versa. In this case, the vertical space between the float and the section (or other) would simply be the maximum between `\intextskip` and the vertical space created by the section (or other macro using `\addvspace`) instead of being the sum of the two spaces, generating large blanks on the page. I'll edit my post to clarify.

Comment: The bad news is that \intextesp is added by \output, which is the most complex and tricky command in LaTeX.

Comment: Note that using `h` means `ht` since LaTeX automatically substitutes the latter. Is `ht` the behaviour you actually want?

Comment: @cfr For this MWE I wanted to simplify things, but in reality in my documents I use  `\def\fps@figure{htbp}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution when I stumbled across this answer from Frank Mittelbach : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40363/209693.

This answer solves the problem raised in the LaTeX2e source document and mentioned in my question, but it also solves the main problem of my question.